# Upgraded to grails 3 and now get unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsParameterMap

Tags: gradle, grails, groovy

unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsParameterMap
 @ line 4, column 1.
   import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsParameterMap

This happened when I upgraded grails from 2.2.4 to 3.1.3.

Is there some new place I need to import this too?  Or is there a dependency I need to add to my gradle build file?

Answer (score 2):

See step 5 on this page, https://docs.grails.org/3.0.x/guide/upgrading.html

> Step 5 - Modify Package Imports In Grails 3.x all internal APIs can be
>   found in the org.grails package and public facing APIs in the grails
>   package. The org.codehaus.groovy.grails package no longer exists.
>
> All package declaration in sources should be modified for the new
>   location of the respective classes. Example
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplication is now
>   grails.core.GrailsApplication.

Comment: Getting the same problem with LocaleAwareNumberConverter.  I moved down to 3.1.1 and am following this documentation http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/api/index-all.html.

unable to resolve class org.grails.databinding.converters.web.LocaleAwareNumberConverter

I feel like I have the right import based on this https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-databinding/src/main/groovy/org/grails/databinding/converters/web/LocaleAwareNumberConverter.groovy

Am I missing a dependency in my build.gradle?